# Get data in zip(*image, *mask) of multi-class classification Unet

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning

I am using Unet for multi-class classification with 8 channels(5x1 channel, 1x3 channel)

However, in this part, I am not sure if I am correctly obtaining the data from train_generators.

```
for i in range(6):
    img, mask = data[i], data[i + len(image_folder)]
```

But I believe that "for i in range(6):" is correct because when I print img_batch, it shows the shape as 8 channels. Also, adjusting the range would result in a shape error when concatenating.

The issue lies with

```
img, mask = data[i], data[i + len(image_folder)]
```

I'm not sure  img, mask  correctly obtained data from train_generators.

I tried to print train_generators but appear error message
main.py

```
folders = [

    'data/syu/train1day/auto_correlation_reverse', #1channel
    'data/syu/train1day/energy',                   #1channel
    'data/syu/train1day/entropy_reverse',          #1channel
    'data/syu/train1day/homogeneity',              #1channel
    'data/syu/train1day/temprature',               #1channel
    'data/syu/train1day/clahe',                    #3channel  
    'data/syu/train2day/auto_correlation_reverse',
    'data/syu/train2day/energy',
    'data/syu/train2day/entropy_reverse',
    'data/syu/train2day/homogeneity',
    'data/syu/train2day/temprature',
    'data/syu/train2day/clahe',
    'data/syu/train3day/auto_correlation_reverse',
    'data/syu/train3day/energy',
    'data/syu/train3day/entropy_reverse',
    'data/syu/train3day/homogeneity',
    'data/syu/train3day/temprature',
    'data/syu/train3day/clahe',
    'data/syu/train4day/auto_correlation_reverse',
    'data/syu/train4day/energy',
    'data/syu/train4day/entropy_reverse',
    'data/syu/train4day/homogeneity',
    'data/syu/train4day/temprature',
    'data/syu/train4day/clahe',

]
myGene = trainGenerator(1, folders, ['image1','image2','image3','image4'], ['label1','label2','label3','label4'],data_gen_args,save_to_dir = None)
```

data.py

```
def trainGenerator(batch_size, train_paths, image_folder, mask_folder, ...)
    for train_path in train_paths:
        image_generator = image_datagen.flow_from_directory(train_path,...)
        mask_generator = mask_datagen.flow_from_directory(train_path,...)
        image_generators.append(image_generator)
        mask_generators.append(mask_generator)

    train_generators = zip(*image_generators, *mask_generators)

    for data in train_generators:   
        for i in range(6):
            img, mask = data[i], data[i + len(image_folder)]   
            images.append(img)
            masks.append(mask)
        img_batch = np.concatenate(images, axis=3) #(1, 512, 512, 8)
        mask_batch = np.concatenate(masks, axis=3) #(1, 512, 512, 6)
```